# reduce loading times by parsing sections of data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am working on my first app and it is parsing data from a website. Depending on the user's search it can have to parse through 1000 nodes, which can take up to 30 seconds before the data is displayed in the tableview. What is the general strategy for parsing through the first 30 nodes and not displaying the next 30 until the user scrolls partially through the table view. I used this website ([here](http://www.lwxted.com/blog/2012/smart-data-loading-table-views/)) as an example, but I am having a hard time understanding where to put my parsing method to get it to load 30 nodes at a time.

```
   #import "DataLoader.h"

@implementation DataLoader

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)loadData
{
[self performSelector:@selector(loadDataDelayed) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}

- (void)loadDataDelayed
{

[parsing method here]
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:30];
for (int i = 1; i<=30 ; i++) {
    [array addObject:[propertyList objectAtIndex:i];
}
[delegate.searchResultOfSets addObjectsFromArray:array];
[delegate.tableView reloadData];
// Always remember to set loading to NO whenever you finish loading the data.
delegate.loading = NO;
}
@end
```

But this obviously parses all the data first. Any ideas on how to optimize my parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch only 30 items first, then, when user scrolls down to bottom, again download another 30 items, may be as follows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
        if(indexPath.row == [self.arrayOfItems count] && hasMoreItemsToLoad) 
           [self loadNext30Items];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for being naive. I am new to programming, and I'm not sure how to parse in segments. How do I stop the parse after 30 items and then pick it up where the parse left off?